# Swift-NIO TCP Client auto reconnect

Tags: netty, reconnect, swift-nio

I write a TCP Client in Swift-NIO to connect Netty TCP Server.
I want tcp client can auto reconnect when needed.

```swift
import Foundation
import NIO

class MessageHandler: ChannelInboundHandler {
    let notificationMessage = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Location")
    public typealias InboundIn = ByteBuffer
    public typealias OutboundOut = ByteBuffer
    private var numBytes = 0
    private var task: RepeatedTask? = nil
    private var bootstrap: ClientBootstrap

    init(bootstrap: ClientBootstrap) {
        self.bootstrap = bootstrap
    }

    public func channelActive(context: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        print("Reconnect Successful")

        self.task?.cancel()
        context.fireChannelActive()
    }

    func channelInactive(context: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        self.task = context.channel.eventLoop.scheduleRepeatedTask(initialDelay: TimeAmount.seconds(0), delay: TimeAmount.seconds(10), { (RepeatedTask) in
            print("Reconnecting...")

            try { () -> EventLoopFuture<Channel> in
                return try self.bootstrap.connect(host: SystemUtil.getConfig(key: "IP") as! String, port: SystemUtil.getConfig(key: "TCPPort") as! Int)
                }()
        })

        context.fireChannelInactive()
    }

    public func channelRead(context: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
        var buffer = unwrapInboundIn(data)
        let readableBytes = buffer.readableBytes
        if let message = buffer.readString(length: readableBytes) {
            print(message)
            let dictMessage = ["Location": message]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationMessage , object:MessageHandler.self, userInfo: dictMessage)
        }
    }

    public func errorCaught(context: ChannelHandlerContext, error: Error) {
        print("error: ", error)

        // As we are not really interested getting notified on success or failure we just pass nil as promise to
        // reduce allocations.
        context.close(promise: nil)
    }
}
```

It about works but something not right.
I use eventLoop.scheduleRepeatedTask to check every 10s, when connected then cancel the RepeatedTask.But self.task?.cancel() not work, I looked source code for cancel.
What is the right method to cancel a RepeatedTask? Thanks

```swift
private func cancel0(localCancellationPromise: EventLoopPromise<Void>?) {
        self.eventLoop.assertInEventLoop()
        self.scheduled?.cancel()
        self.scheduled = nil
        self.task = nil

        // Possible states at this time are:
        //  1) Task is scheduled but has not yet executed.
        //  2) Task is currently executing and invoked `cancel()` on itself.
        //  3) Task is currently executing and `cancel0()` has been reentrantly invoked.
        //  4) NOT VALID: Task is currently executing and has NOT invoked `cancel()` (`EventLoop` guarantees serial execution)
        //  5) NOT VALID: Task has completed execution in a success state (`reschedule()` ensures state #2).
        //  6) Task has completed execution in a failure state.
        //  7) Task has been fully cancelled at a previous time.
        //
        // It is desirable that the task has fully completed any execution before any cancellation promise is
        // fulfilled. States 2 and 3 occur during execution, so the requirement is implemented by deferring
        // fulfillment to the next `EventLoop` cycle. The delay is harmless to other states and distinguishing
        // them from 2 and 3 is not practical (or necessarily possible), so is used unconditionally. Check the
        // promises for nil so as not to otherwise invoke `execute()` unnecessarily.
        if self.cancellationPromise != nil || localCancellationPromise != nil {
            self.eventLoop.execute {
                self.cancellationPromise?.succeed(())
                localCancellationPromise?.succeed(())
            }
        }
    }
```

Yes the task is nil so cancel don't work. I change global variable to static

```swift
static var task: RepeatedTask? = nil
```

Now works fine.

But I still not sure what is the best practice with auto reconnect in Swift-NIO.
In my Android App I used Netty for TCP Client like this

```java
private inner class ConnectServerThread : Thread() {
    override fun run() {
        super.run()

        val workerGroup = NioEventLoopGroup()

        try {
            val bootstrap = Bootstrap()
            bootstrap.group(workerGroup)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel::class.java)
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                .handler(object : ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    public override fun initChannel(ch: SocketChannel) {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(
                            ReconnectHandler(bootstrap, channel),
                            StringEncoder(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                            StringDecoder(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                            MessageHandlerAdapter()
                        )
                    }
                })
            val channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(
                InetSocketAddress(
                    ConfigUtil.config!!.ip,
                    ConfigUtil.config!!.tcpPort!!.toInt()
                )
            ).sync()
            channelFuture.addListener {
                getConnectionListener()
            }
            channel = channelFuture.channel() as SocketChannel
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("SystemService", e.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I used ReconnectHandler for reconnect and getConnectionListener for listen.
In Swift-NIO is there similar Listener or other solution?

Comment: `RepeatedTask.cancel` is definitely the right API to use to cancel a repeated task. When you say "it doesn't work", what are you expecting to work? How is `MessageHandler` ending up in the new channel pipeline to receive the `channelActive` notification?

Comment: self.task?.cancel()  can't cancel  repeated task. It still running with loop output: Reconnecting...         Reconnect Successful

Comment: Is the `task` `nil`?

Comment: Yes the task is nil so cancel don't work. I change global variable to static.I supplement some code and words above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for SwiftNIO will require your handler to attach callbacks to the future returned from `connect`. These callbacks can close over the repeating task, and so can cancel it when a connection completes. For example:

```swift
import Foundation
import NIO

final class Reconnector {
    private var task: RepeatedTask? = nil
    private let bootstrap: ClientBootstrap

    init(bootstrap: ClientBootstrap) {
        self.bootstrap = bootstrap
    }

    func reconnect(on loop: EventLoop) {
        self.task = loop.scheduleRepeatedTask(initialDelay: .seconds(0), delay: .seconds(10)) { task in
            print("reconnecting")
            try self._tryReconnect()
        }
    }

    private func _tryReconnect() throws {
        try self.bootstrap.connect(host: SystemUtil.getConfig(key: "IP") as! String, port: SystemUtil.getConfig(key: "TCPPort") as! Int).whenSuccess { _ in
            print("reconnect successful!")
            self.task?.cancel()
            self.task = nil
        }
    }
}

class MessageHandler: ChannelInboundHandler {
    let notificationMessage = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Location")
    public typealias InboundIn = ByteBuffer
    public typealias OutboundOut = ByteBuffer
    private var numBytes = 0
    private let reconnect: Reconnector

    init(bootstrap: ClientBootstrap) {
        self.reconnector = Reconnector(bootstrap: bootstrap)
    }

    func channelInactive(context: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        self.reconnector.reconnect()
        context.fireChannelInactive()
    }

    public func channelRead(context: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
        var buffer = unwrapInboundIn(data)
        let readableBytes = buffer.readableBytes
        if let message = buffer.readString(length: readableBytes) {
            print(message)
            let dictMessage = ["Location": message]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationMessage , object:MessageHandler.self, userInfo: dictMessage)
        }
    }

    public func errorCaught(context: ChannelHandlerContext, error: Error) {
        print("error: ", error)

        // As we are not really interested getting notified on success or failure we just pass nil as promise to
        // reduce allocations.
        context.close(promise: nil)
    }
}
```